# Como fazer um clone/snapshot de um container Docker com todos os dados?

Tags: docker

Estou tentando fazer um clone ou um snapshot de um container do **Docker** e todo o seu conteúdo.

Mais especificamente falando, tenho dois container onde rodam bases dados, um com `Cassandra` e outro com `MySQL`. Eles são usados em testes, por isso gostaria de peguar um *Snapshot* disso e copiar em outro container para poder usar sem "estragar" o original, porém não tive sucesso em fazer isso.

Pesquisando sobre backups/clone/snapshots de containers, cheguei aos comandos [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) e [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) que salva a imagem e depois pode ser carregada em outro container, porém não tive sucesso com ambos.

O que acontece é que consigo copiar e inclusive configurações, mas não os dados das instâncias dos bancos, isso vem vazio.

Poderia gerar scripts para fazer isso, e toda vez que precisar criar um novo container e executar os scripts, mas acredito que um clone/snapshot seria mais simples e me parece algo trivial, só que não sei como fazer :(

Então a minha dúvida é: como fazer um backup ou snapshot de um container do Docker e criar um novo, mantendo os dados, especialmente os dados de um container com um banco de dados, suas tabelas e dados?

Comment: Como quer fazer um backup dos dados do container o [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) não resolveria isso? O ideal seria você usar volumes, daí iria manter a persistência dos seus dados...

Comment: mas usando o `docker cp` eu preciso informar as pastas/arquivos que eu quero copiar certo? eu gostaria de algo mais simples como se fosse `docker cp cointainer-origem to container-destino`

Comment: Entendi, via docker não conheço uma feature que faça isso :/

Comment: cria um checkpoint https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/checkpoint/

Comment: @AdirKuhn li o link do comando, e esse é um comando experimental certo? mas a dúvida é: crio o checkpoint, e depois como restauro em outra máquina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia de um container é exatamente essa, não ter que criar clones ou snapshots, isso é a função de uma VM.

Como dito nos comentários, o melhor caminho é utilizar o comando `docker cp` encontrado nesse [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/), pegando os arquivos necessários utilizando `/path/to/file:name.txt` or `./file:name.txt`.

Outra opção é fazer um `Dump` da suas bases [MySql](https://gist.github.com/geraldvillorente/4c60e7fdb5562f443f16ad2bbe4235ce) e do seu Cassandra.

Como boa prática, o correto é montar um volume local com sua base e direcionar seus container para esse volume.

Comment: "*A ideia de um container é exatamente essa*", isso é um ponto a se pensar não tinha pensado dessa maneira, de qualquer forma não aceito a ideia de não poder "clonar" um container completo, e me parece que é uma situação que pode acontecer com outras pessoas. De qualquer forma, vou testar o comando `docker cp`, mas imagino que isso não seja prático: eu, como developer, sei usar comandos sql, configurar o banco, etc, mas não faço ideia onde estão os arquivos do banco para copiá-los, e mais, se só copiar funciona? com `sql-server` e `oracle` que conheço um pouco mais não, tem de registrar

Comment: então apesar de possivelmente permitir copiar, não é uma solução, provavelmente teria de escrever um script que faça todo o trabalho, e tem de conhecer a estrutura de pastas/arquivos do `MySql` e do `Cassandra`. Mas se não tiver jeito, vai ser assim mesmo :)

Comment: Nesse link: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql mais específico em `Where to Store Data`, mostra exatamente aonde fica o diretório de sua base para utilizar o `docker  cp`, o mesmo funciona para o `Cassandra` nesse link https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra

Comment: Caso queira usar um docker de forma estática para suas informações, recomendo a leitura de https://www.infoworld.com/article/3106416/containerizing-stateful-applications.html

Comment: embora não tenha resolvido extamente o que eu gostaria, é o mais próximo que consegui